# How to read a particular range in excel in c#?

Tags: c#, excel

How to read rows from particular column range ("A4" ) to column("G4") and underneath all rows.

```
    Excel.Worksheet worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Worksheets["Trading Desks"];

    Excel.Range range = worksheet.get_Range("A4:G4", Type.Missing);
    int rowCount = range.Rows.Count;
    int colCount = range.Columns.Count;

    //access the cells
    for (int row = 1; row <= rowCount; ++row)
    {
       for (int col = 1; col <= colCount; ++col)
       {

       }
    }
```

But I am getting always getting one row count. How to get all rows and get values from it?

Answer (score 0):

The reason your row count equals 1 is because your range only covers one row.

The second character in the cell name indicates what row it's in. For example, `A4` is column A, row 4, while `B2` is column B, row 2.

So all of the cells in your range belong to row 4, meaning that you'll get a row count of exactly 1.

Try changing the cells your range covers to something like `A4:G6` and see if that works.

Comment: that is the problem. I don't know where rows going to end.it may be G6 or G100. How to find end column?